# how would i make a sprite go in front and behind a 2d wall?

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, tilemap

I've tried a few solutions but none seem to work. first, I tried adding half of that same sprite onto the original and then making the layer higher, which would work, except my original sprite can walk so far behind the wall that only its head is sticking out from behind, so if I were to use that strategy I would only be able to add the top of its head, otherwise you would see half the sprite go over the wall while walking behind it, which would look weird. the second option I saw was making different parts of the tilemap walls different layers, but for my specific tilemap, I am unable to unless there is some way of making each individual tile multiple layers. any ideas?[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve or how it should look like?

Comment: [Does this previous Q&A help at all?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/181632/39518) If not, can you edit your question to show us in more detail how your situation is set up, how you've tried applying the fix described at that link, and where it's failing?