# Sprite sorting is working fine but tilemap sorting is working the opposite way I want it to

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, tilemap, sorting

I provided some screenshots to display what I'm talking about. The blue tile is a sprite, and the bushes are made from tilemap, each being 4 16x16 tiles. My transparency sort axis is set to 0,1,0. I've tried messing with the Z value in the axis as well to no avail. I'll also point out that if I switch my sort axis to 0, -1, 0,   the tile map sorting begins to work and the sprite sorting stops working. [image: behind sprite]

[image: in front of sprite]

[image: in front of tilemap]
[image: behind tilemap]

Comment: Does this help? [Issue with Sorting Layers with an NPC and Tilemap](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/181632/39518)

Comment: @DMGregory sorry no I already saw that thread and the problem they're talking about has more to do with the way the scene is rendered being inconsistent, also I've already implemented the solution for that question into my project

Comment: Can you show us how your Tilemap Renderer component is configured in the inspector?

Comment: @DMGregory wow I'm a complete idiot, I thought my draw mode for that layer was set to individual but it was set to chunk. After changing it to individual it partially solves my problem but there's still some issues that I'll probably have to do some more research on. Thank you for your help, you were right to link that other thread.

Comment: I'll put this question on hold as a duplicate of the other for the moment. If you find you still need help with it, edit the question to demonstrate the remaining issue you're struggling with and we can re-open that refined question for answers.