# Drawing Sort Order in Unity Tilemap

Tags: unity, tilemap

I don't know if this is something I'm doing wrong or if it's a bug with the Tilemap system in Unity.

Right now I am spawning a 100x100 grid of cells with a texture on z-axis 0.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
    {
        tileMap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0), tilebase);
    }
}
```

I am then using `SetTile to add a new texture on z-axis 1 in a grid (this is me dragging out a rectangular area of tiles while holding down a mouse button)
Each frame, it removes the old tiles on z-axis 1 and replaces them with a new grid of tiles.

```
selectionArea = new RectInt(selectionArea.x, selectionArea.y, 
                            selectedTile.x - selectionArea.x, 
                            selectedTile.y - selectionArea.y);
var selectionAreaPos = GetPositiveRect(selectionArea);
var lastSelectionPos = GetPositiveRect(lastSelection);
Debug.Log($"Pos: {selectionAreaPos} // {lastSelectionPos}");
for (int x = lastSelectionPos.x; x <= lastSelectionPos.x + lastSelectionPos.width; x++)
{
    for (int y = lastSelectionPos.y; y <= lastSelectionPos.y + lastSelectionPos.height; y++)
    {
        tileMap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 1), null);
    }
}
// this is here just to show I have used both a for loop and BoxFill when attempting to get this to function
//for (int x = selectionAreaPos.x; x <= selectionAreaPos.x + selectionAreaPos.width; x++)
//{
//    for (int y = selectionAreaPos.y; y <= selectionAreaPos.y + selectionAreaPos.height; y++)
//    {
//        tileMap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 1), (buttonDown == 1 ? tiletest1 : tiletest2));
//    }
//}
tileMap.BoxFill(new Vector3Int(selectedTile.x, selectedTile.y, 1), 
                (buttonDown == 1 ? tiletest1 : tiletest2), 
                selectionAreaPos.x, selectionAreaPos.y, 
                selectionAreaPos.x + selectionAreaPos.width, 
                selectionAreaPos.y + selectionAreaPos.height);
```

When I let go of the mouse button, it then uses set tile to place the tiles on z-axis 0.

```
selectionArea = new RectInt(selectionArea.x, selectionArea.y, selectedTile.x - selectionArea.x, selectedTile.y - selectionArea.y);
var selectionAreaPos = GetPositiveRect(selectionArea);
var lastSelectionPos = GetPositiveRect(lastSelection);
for (int x = lastSelectionPos.x; x <= lastSelectionPos.x + lastSelectionPos.width; x++)
{
    for (int y = lastSelectionPos.y; y <= lastSelectionPos.y + lastSelectionPos.height; y++)
    {
        tileMap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 1), null);
    }
}
for (int x = selectionAreaPos.x; x <= selectionAreaPos.x + selectionAreaPos.width; x++)
{
    for (int y = selectionAreaPos.y; y <= selectionAreaPos.y + selectionAreaPos.height; y++)
    {
        tileMap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(x, y, 0), (buttonDown == 1 ? tiletest1 : tiletest2));
    }
}
```

However, depending on previous tile placements and the Sort Order of the tilemap, the dragged out tiles on z-axis 1 will sometimes appear behind the existing tiles on z-axis 0, as shown below:

[image: Starting with some pre-placed tiles]

Starting with some pre-placed tiles

[image]

Dragging out some new tiles, starting at X, dragging up and left to O. You'll note it draws over the bottom two paving tiles.

[image]

Once I reach the same x,y axis as the top left paved tile, *all* paved tiles are now drawn in front of my z-axis 1 cobble tiles, even though they are on z-axis 0.

This seems to depend entirely on which tile is getting drawn first from the top left for all instances of the tile.

My guess so far is this is due to me declaring the `TileBase` tiles as:

```
public TileBase tilebase;
public TileBase tiletest1;
public TileBase tiletest2;
```

I'm currently thinking maybe each tile needs to be its own instance, though I'm not sure how.
But this may be down to me wanting to use the grid system for a player map editor rather than a fixed editor in Unity.

Would I be better off just making my own grid system for a game where tiles can change?

Here's the Tilemap & grid components as set up in the inspector.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the configuration of your tilemap component in the inspector?

Comment: @DMGregory added images of tilemap (and grid)

Comment: I notice you're using the "Chunk" sort mode for your tilemap. This has some limitations that might be affecting your use case — [I go into a bit more depth on this in a previous answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/181813/39518)

Comment: Hi @DMGregory unfortunately I'm using the Universal Render Pipeline, so those graphics options aren't available in Edit > Project Settings > Graphics > Transparency > Sort Axis.  But it's worth noting that if I change my sort mode to Individual I encounter the same issue