# Sorting tile unity problem

Tags: unity, tilemap, tiles, draw-order, top-down

I have a top down Tiled map, and I would like to extract every single tile from the map and set z order layer according to the Y position they have, I have already found the way to have every single Tilebase but I can't change sorting layer ... .

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? [There may be easier ways to get correct sorting behaviour](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/181813/39518).

Comment: Thanks, it worked, the only thing I had to do different is where to find the setting since I am using URP

Comment: You may want to add a new answer to the question linked above then, showing how to configure the settings correctly for URP.