# Sorting layer of wall in top down game 2d

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, layers, sorting

I made tilemap using tiled app.

I try to sort layer so the when the  player is in front of wall he visible and when he is behind the wall then not viable, it's commonsense.
But problem only one line of wall layer is sort by x=0 y=1 z=0 and other line of wall is show player always overlap it. Even when all wall structure is of same layer I made in tiled. How to solve it?

Comment: Does this help? [Issue with Sorting Layers with an NPC and Tilemap](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/181632/39518)